# Having problems with fabric8-maven-plugin

Tags: apache-karaf, jbossfuse, karaf, fabric8

I have come to a problem which I'm not exactly sure how to resolve.

Following the fabric8.io manual I have configured the maven plugin and placed every single configuration bit where it should be placed.

However once I execute the mvn fabric8:deploy I always get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:1.0.0.redhat-355:
deploy (default-cli) on project ag: Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.compa
ny.ag:ag:0.1-00.00.B01-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata
com.company.ag:ag:0.1-00.00.B01-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to fabric8.uplo
ad.repo (http://127.0.0.1:8181/maven/upload/): Error transferring file: Server
returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://127.0.0.1:8181/maven/upload/co
m/company/ag/ag/0.1-00.00.B01-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml -> [Help 1]
```

Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Thanks a lot, 
Tiho

Comment: Can you see any errors or something on the server log, as it returned 503. it may have logged something.

Comment: And maybe try with a simpler version number, not sure if its invalid - eg try with 0.1-SNAPSHOT instead.

Comment: Indeed tried with this. However it didn't help shortening the name. Then logs are not really helpful, actually once you check the logs there is nothing inside. The other project showed the same. 
Important to mention is that this is being done on Windows 7. Not sure if it matters?

Comment: build 355 is a bit old, try with build 378 you can download here: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/ea/org/jboss/fuse/jboss-fuse-full/

Comment: That is what I'm usingindeed. build 378. Let's presume that I don't want to import the project into the local maven cache, I can use the directive upload=false. And this is somethow OK, the profile gets created. Then I would expect when I create instance from the profile to have the instance created, and artifacts downloaded... however next problem appears there, that even though I have our repositories in the agent configuration of default profile... simply states that it cannot find them... whcih is strange.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are behind the proxy. Then try to add your computer litteral name to your maven settings.xml in nonProxyHosts section:

```
<proxies>
<proxy>
  <username>proxy_user</username>
  <password>proxy_pass</password>
  <port>proxy_port</port>
  <host>proxy_url</host>
  <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1|YourComputerName</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Hi Igor, thanks for your Answer indeed. We have actually quit the idea of creating local repository that way. Instead as a workaround we are simply creating the directory structure in the <fabric8_homedie>/system which is then referred from the features.xml and adding custom repository in the profile we use to create an instance. That way it perfectly works.